# How can I position these elements (and future elements) to my own accord, without them bing "locked" in place by a layout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

I have a created a GUI in PyQt5. I have 1 current widget, and others to come soon, that I want to put on my GUI. However, I can't find a way to postion them however I want. I am using things like grid layouts, but they only allow "locked" places i.e. (0,1) (1,0) (1,1), I don't think they allow you to just use things like move() to position the elements.

I have already tried, as mentioned, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayout. I have also tried groups.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Settings():
    SCENE_SIZE_X = 1200
    SCENE_SIZE_Y = 900
    GRID_COUNT_X = 4
    GRID_COUNT_Y = 5
    GRID_BOX_WIDTH = 100
    GRID_BOX_HEIGHT = 100

class Grid(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.lines = []
        self.scrolled = 0
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.draw_grid(Settings.GRID_COUNT_X, Settings.GRID_COUNT_Y, Settings.GRID_BOX_WIDTH, Settings.GRID_BOX_HEIGHT)
        self.set_opacity(1.0)

    def draw_grid(self, x_count, y_count, x_size, y_size):
        width = x_count * x_size
        height = y_count * y_size
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.setItemIndexMethod(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)

        pen = QPen(QColor(0,0,0), 1, Qt.SolidLine)

        for x in range(0,x_count+1):
            xc = x * x_size
            self.lines.append(self.addLine(xc,0,xc,height,pen))
            self.addText

        for y in range(0,y_count+1):
            yc = y * y_size
            self.lines.append(self.addLine(0,yc,width,yc,pen))

    def set_opacity(self,opacity):
        for line in self.lines:
            line.setOpacity(opacity)

    def delete_grid(self):
        for line in self.lines:
            self.removeItem(line)
        del self.lines[:]

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        self.scrolled += event.delta()/90
        if(self.scrolled > -30.0):
            self.delete_grid()
            self.draw_grid(Settings.GRID_COUNT_X, Settings.GRID_COUNT_Y, Settings.GRID_BOX_WIDTH + self.scrolled, Settings.GRID_BOX_HEIGHT + self.scrolled)
        else:
            self.scrolled = -30.0

class App(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 100, Settings.SCENE_SIZE_X, Settings.SCENE_SIZE_Y)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(Grid())

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(grid, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("hello!"), 0, 0)
        layout.setRowStretch(2, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am getting the elements to show up, just not where I want them to be located as I am using layouts.

As I mentioned, I did try groups and they *sort of* worked. I got everything correct but it looked messy as there were widgets inside of groups, inside of groups:

[image: Picture of me trying groups]

What is the best way to allow me to position them to, maybe, single pixel precision, i.e. using move()?

Thanks,
Dream

EDIT: the code and the image don't line up becuase it was an old iteration of the code

Comment: I do not understand what you want to obtain, what is your goal ?, on the other hand if you use a layout you can not use move, that is, if you choose one the other will not work. The layout is a non-visible element that handles the size and position of the widgets that are assigned to them.

Comment: Pretty much what I am asking is how can I use .move() for my widgets? I am currently using a grid layout but they only allow for positions like grid (0,1) not "screen" positions like (0.345, 1.443).

Comment: Like this, but working:
```- 
grid = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(Grid())
grid.move(50,20)
grid.show()
```